# Delete Contents of Bootable USB on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, unetbootin

When I boot into Windows (7), my bootable USB (that I created with UNetBootin) is not showing the correct size. I think the space taken up by the bootable portion is not showing up. I want to wipe the entire USB including the bootable bits. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this from outside the running operating system, ie boot up a computer and mount the stick there.

Then you can partition the whole drive. You might want to use [fdisk](/questions/tagged/fdisk) if you want a unix command line tool, [gparted](/questions/tagged/gparted) if you want a unix GUI or something like Partition Magic if you are running Windows to wipe the entire USB including the boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Disk Management console.  One way to get to it is Right-click on Computer and select Manage, then choose the Disk Managment task in the left panel.  In the middle-bottom, you should see each of your disks.  Find the USB drive and delete the partitions then recreate a single partition of the size and type you want.